# python - abbreviation program with index accessing from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this:

```
print ('Ask me some abbreviations :)')

v_file = open('abbreviations.txt','r')
v_abbrv = v_file.read()
v_exit = 'yes'

while v_exit != 'no':
    v_word = str(raw_input('Abbreviation ? '))
    if v_word == 'LOL':
        print 'LOL means:',(v_abbrv[5:19])
    elif v_word == 'ROLF':
        print 'ROLF means :',(v_abbrv[26:55])
    elif v_word == 'ACE':
        print 'ACE means: ',(v_abbrv[61:78])
    elif v_word == 'AD':
        print 'AD means: ',(v_abbrv[83:95])
    elif v_word == 'AFAIR':
        print 'AFAIR means: ',(v_abbrv[103:123])
    elif v_word == 'AFK':
       print 'AFK means:',(v_abbrv[129:147])
    elif v_word == 'ANI':
       print 'ANI means:',(v_abbrv[153:170])
    elif v_word == 'CUL':
       print 'CUL means:',(v_abbrv[175:189])
    elif v_word == 'CWYL':
       print 'CWYL means:',(v_abbrv[196:216])
    elif v_word == 'IQ':
       print 'IQ means:',(v_abbrv[220:238])
    elif v_word == 'BA':
       print 'BA means:',(v_abbrv[243:259])
    elif v_word == 'BS':
       print 'BS means:',(v_abbrv[264:284])
    elif v_word == 'MA':
       print 'MA means:',(v_abbrv[288:302])
    elif v_word == 'JD':
       print 'JD means:',(v_abbrv[307:319])
    elif v_word == 'DC':
       print 'DC means:',(v_abbrv[324:346])
    elif v_word == 'PA':
       print 'PA means:',(v_abbrv[346:369])
    elif v_word == 'MD':
       print 'MD means:',(v_abbrv[371:391])
    elif v_word == 'VP':
       print 'VP means:',(v_abbrv[396:410])
    elif v_word == 'SVP':
       print 'SVP means:',(v_abbrv[416:437])
    elif v_word == 'EVP':
       print 'EVP means:',(v_abbrv[443:467])
    elif v_word == 'CMO':
       print 'CMO means:',(v_abbrv[473:497])
    elif v_word == 'CFO':
       print 'CFO means:',(v_abbrv[502:524])
    elif v_word == 'CEO':
       print 'CEO means:',(v_abbrv[531:555])
    v_exit = str(raw_input('Ask more?yes\\no: '))
```

and this are the contents of the loaded text file:

```
LOL, laugh out loud
ROLF, rolling on the floor laughing
ACE, a cool experience
AD, awesome dude
AFAIR, as far as I remember
AFK, away from keyboard
ANI, age not important
CUL, see you later
CWYL, chat with you later
IQ, ignorance quotient
BA, Bachelor of Arts
BS, Bachelor of Science
MA, Master of Arts
JD, Juris Doctor
DC, Doctor of Chiropractic
PA, Personal Assistant
MD, Managing Director
VP, Vice President
SVP, Senior Vice President
EVP, Executive Vice President
CMO, Chief Marketing Officer
CFO, Chief Financial Officer
CEO, Chief Executive Officer
```

I just finished a couple of minutes ago and it works fine but i have a feeling that this is not the way for doing it though, isn't it? I'm just curious on some opinions from somebody out there. It is said that if it works, then it's ok, but i don't think i can say this in this case. So what do you think? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better first read the file into a dictionary:

```
abbrevs = {}
with open('abbreviations.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        short, long = line.rstrip().split(',', 1)
        abbrevs[short] = long
```

You can then find the abbreviation by a simple lookup in the dictionary:

```
v_word = str(raw_input('Abbreviation ? '))
if v_word not in abbrevs:
    print "Don't know what that means."
else:
    print "{} means {}".format(v_word, abbrevs[v_word])
```

Comment: use rstrip if you want to remove newlines

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that's clearer, although technically, in some situations it can strip white space you want to keep. I'll update the answer.

Comment: i don't understand the line "short, long = line.rstrip().split(',', 1)"...how it works? also the line "with open('abbreviations.txt') as f:" is f an alias variable for the contents of 'abbreviations.txt'?

Comment: @udarH3 `f` is the opened file. It's like writing `f = open('abbreviations.txt')` except however the `with` block is left, whether normally or by an error, the file is ensured to be closed. As to the `short, long = ...` assignment, the left side is a tuple and the right side returns a list of size 2, the elements of which are stored in the left-side elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use a dict. like this:

```
d = dict()
d['LOL'] = [5,19]
d['ROLF']= [26,55]
// other indexes

while v_exit != 'no':
    v_word = str(raw_input('Abbreviation ? '))
    print '%sL means: %s', % (v_word, (v_abbrv[d[v_word][0], d[v_word][1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines of your file into a dictionary by:

1. readlines() to get each line
2. split(', ') to split the lines based on a delimeter of ', ' and assign to a and b.
3. rstrip() to strip out newline characters from dictionary assignment of b to a.
4. Finally check to see if the users entry is in the dict and print if it is.

Hope this helps.

```
v_file = open('abbreviations.txt','r')
v_dict = {}
v_word = raw_input('Enter an abbreviation: ')

# add abbreviations and meanings to a dictionary
for line in v_file.readlines():
    a, b = line.split(', ')
    v_dict[a] = b.rstrip()

# lookup meanings of abbreviations
if v_word in v_dict:
    print(v_dict[v_word])
```